# Aurelia Child Sub Router

Tags: javascript, aurelia

So I have an issue where my sub router is not working when I throw it in a template. Here is what I mean:

My app.js has this route which works:

```
{
   route: ['accounts'],
   name: 'accounts',
   moduleId: '../accounts/account-router',
   nav: false,
   title: 'QualBoard',
},
```

In accounts-router I have (which works):

```
export class AccountRouter {
  configureRouter(config) {
    config.map([
      {
        route: [':accountId'],
        name: 'account',
        moduleId: './account',
        nav: false,
        title: 'QualBoard',
      },
      {
        route: [':id/users'],
        name: 'users',
        moduleId: '../users/users-router',
        nav: false,
        title: 'QualBoard',
      },
    ]);
  }
}
```

Inside of account.html I have a template call to another route :

```
<template>
  <require from="./account-overview.html"></require>
  <require from="./sub-view/subview-router"></require>

  <div class="content-panel">
    <account-overview account.bind="account"></account-overview>
    <subview-router></subview-router>
  </div>
</template>
```

So the subview router looks like so:

```
export class SubviewRouter {

  configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.map([
      {
        route: ['projects', ''],
        name: 'projects',
        moduleId: './projects',
        nav: true,
        title: 'Projects',
        settings: {
          class: 'icon-ion-briefcase',
        },
      },
    ]);

    this.router = router;
  }
}
```

And the subview-router.html:

```
<template>
  <router-view containerless></router-view>
</template>
```

All the routes work but the final subview router. Oddly I can take the code in subview router and add it into my account.js file as well as swap out  with  and it will work. Why is the subview router not working?

Comment: Are you trying to hook the router pipeline in a custom element? I don't think that's possible, and I also don't think it makes sense. Not sure if I understood your problem though...

Comment: I mean, only elements which were called by router can have a subrouter. In your case, SubviewRouter was not called by the router

Comment: Ah I noticed it worked in account.js but not the subview-router. I figured it would be the same really. Was wanting to abstract my router code out of the account.js

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your nav: false to nav:true.